# Непредвиденный знак $

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TimeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SYSTEMTIME t;
            GetLocalTime(out t);
            Console.WriteLine($"{t.wYear}/{t.wMonth}/{t.wDay} {t.wHour}:{t.wMinute}:{t.wSecond}");
        }
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern void GetLocalTime(out SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
    struct SYSTEMTIME
    {
        public ushort wYear;
        public ushort wMonth;
        public ushort wDayOfWeek;
        public ushort wDay;
        public ushort wHour;
        public ushort wMinute;
        public ushort wSecond;
        public ushort wMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

При компиляции выдаёт ошибку в коде: `Console.WriteLine` - **Непредвиденный знак $**

В чём его особенность?

И как его использовать?

На данный момент тестировал на **Net.4.0**

Comment: C#6 *(11 символов нужно...)*

Comment: @ArteS  Используйте знак @ вместо $. Этот знак используется для объявления "буквальных" строковых литералов.

Comment: Да я просто очень часто встречаю знак $, вот и решил узнать с чем его едят, спс что объяснили)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ему же, вроде, interpolated string нужна

Comment: Версия .NET не имеет значения. Доступен в C#6 => VS2015 и выше. В настройках билда проекта должен быть выбран стандарт C#6 или выше

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это нововведение C#6 называется "интерполяция строк".

Этот символ позволяет указывать переменные, окруженные фигурными скобками, прямо в строках без использования конкатенации или форматирования.

Например, вместо того, чтобы писать:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5}", 
    t.wYear, t.wMonth, t.wDay, t.wHour, t.wMinute, t.wSecond));
```

или

```
Console.WriteLine(t.wYear + "/" + t.wMonth + "/" + t.wDay + " " + t.wHour + ":" + t.wMinute + ":" + t.wSecond);
```

Гораздо читабельнее выглядит так:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{t.wYear}/{t.wMonth}/{t.wDay} {t.wHour}:{t.wMinute}:{t.wSecond}");
```

Интерполяция строк была введена в версии C#6.

Если у Вас данная запись не проходит проверку синтаксиса, попробуйте обновиться до Visual Studio 2015.

Также рекомендую почитать статью на MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn961160.aspx